# Does Jane Kaczmarek actually whistle in "Mrs. Tri-County"?

Tags: soundtrack, credits, malcolm-in-the-middle

In the finale to season 6 of *Malcolm in the Middle*, Lois whistles impressively on stage.  I can't seem to find a credit for who actually did the whistling: was it recorded (and from whom), or does the actress herself actually have that particular talent?

Comment: No idea, but guessing they hired a professional whistler rather than base the season finale on an obscure skill of Kaczmarek's (which she seemingly never boasted about). They can't all be [Skinny Pete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_974ZusIvhk). ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The episode aired in May 2005, and an [article](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEVr_yM1lVZ1QA6ScnnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEycXN2dTI2BGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMyBHZ0aWQDQjAxMjdfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1431938163/RO=10/RU=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seattleweekly.com%2F2005-05-25%2Farts%2Fjust-put-your-lips-together%2F/RK=0/RS=0CAhwsrOeqp3_Gi2ixu8hFnrAVY-) in the the *Seattle News* from October 2006 (*Just Put Your Lips Together*) discusses the career of pro whistler Steve Herbst, mentioning that he "recently contributed to an episode of Malcolm in the Middle." Think this must be your man.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).